# Strong reference to self inside a method running from a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

So, I know that if you save a block inside of `self`, then access `self` inside of that block you need to create and use something like  `__weak id weakSelf = self;`.

My question is, does this also extend to functions being called from that block? As in, would the following lead to a retain cycle:

```
self.block = ^{ [weakSelf myFunction]; }
- (void) myFunction { self.counter++; }
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: No. It only retains objects referenced within the body of the block itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not create a retain cycle, because the `self` in the method is actually a parameter passed by the Objective C runtime (using [`objc_msgSend`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend) and similar). So let's consider the two scenarios possible in your code example. `weakSelf` has been zeroed out due to release of the holding object - a message passed to `nil` is ignored. `weakSelf` is not zeroed, in which case, it is passed by the Objective C runtime to the message as its `self` parameter.